# How to strip text from node

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a node that contains `<h2>This is a <a href="....">nice</a> text (12.4)</h2>` and I want to strip the stuff between brackets and then apply templates:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>`

(dot has the node and I want to keep the `<a>`, but I can do that with another template)

How can In do that within the select attribute?

`<xsl:apply-templates select="replace(. , '\([0-9\.]*\)', '' )"/>` does not work, I know, because a node is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function on text nodes, for instance

`<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="replace(. , '\([0-9\.]*\)', '' )"/></xsl:template>`

Of course you need to make sure your text nodes are processed by using apply-templates but you should have seen enough examples of using the identity transformation template and its overrides by now to figure it out.

And if needed you can of course refine the match pattern to e.g `match="h2//text()"` if needed.